# Missing photos after inserting external sd card into Samsung galaxy Tab s6 lite

Tags: sd-card, data-recovery, samsung-galaxy-tab

*I want to appologize in advance if this is the wrong forum.*

### Whats the problem?

I am photographing on my fuji xt4 and wanted to transfer all photos to my Samsung galaxy S6 Lite (using a basic card reader). The storage is correctly recognized and mounted. The first few times were no problem. However now all photos up from a certain point are not displayed/lost. Once inserted into the tablet the new photos and Videos are permanently gone (the camera doesnt displays them either).

- Sony tough sd card 64gb (exFat)
- Fujifilm xt4
- Samsung galaxy tab s6lite (Android 11, not rooted)

#### What i tried

- rebooting the tablet
- reinserting the sd card
- different card reader
- accessing the photos by connecting to the camera via ptp is no problem
- using more powerful file browser did not reveal anything new

I have currently no access to a normal computer and therefore cant properly investigate the problem further. I tried nearly all recovery android Apps but none scanned extertal USB storage. My last idea was to mask the card reader as internal sd card but Samsung seems to Block adoptable storage and any further advances in included formating the sd card.
My best guess is that my tablet is resetting the block-bitmap from the sd card to the state of the last time it was mounted.
Has anyone an idea on what is happening and what the best approach in recovering the lost data may be?